# Facing a issue in converting a code snippet of vb into c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am facing an issue in converting a VB code into C#. Please look at the code snippet below.

```
Public Class readyforemail
    Public returnedhtml As String
    Public cid_image() As cid_image_construct
    Public Sub New(ByVal i As Integer)
        Erase cid_image
        ReDim cid_image(i)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class cid_image_construct
    Public cid As String
    Public imagedata As String
End Class
```

Comment: How we know what was the issues that you are facing?

Comment: Please show your current effort and advise that issue you're facing.

Comment: '''Public cid_image() As cid_image_construct''' unable to convert specifically this part in C# .Is  this an array of a class cid_image_construct?

Comment: [Arrays in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) vs [Arrays in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

Comment: Can you please share how to write this in C# Public cid_image() As cid_image_construct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you think about what the type of `cid_image` is, and then research how to declare a variable of that type in C#. (Doing this will put you into a much better position for further work than us just giving you the answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciate it..

Answer (score 1):

Use online code converter. http://converter.telerik.com/

```
public class readyforemail
{
    public string returnedhtml;
    public cid_image_construct[] cid_image;
    public readyforemail(int i)
    {
        cid_image = null;
        cid_image = new cid_image_construct[i + 1];
    }
}

public class cid_image_construct
{
    public string cid;
    public string imagedata;
}
```